# What value should I use as modulo value for blum blum shub generator

Tags: matlab

The modulo value for blum blum shub generator is a product of 2 prime numbers. But what value should I use for generating 256 bit sequence? Which value provides good security?

Comment: The name of that method is totally hilarious.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with MATLAB programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question probably off topic in Stackoverflow, but the name of the algorithm is so hilarious (sorry original authors) that I am going to try to answer it.

Generally I am going to refer to their original paper. You can find it in:

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0215025

The B.B.S gererator follows equation:

[image]

Where N is the product of two primes of the same length (I hope someone can clarify what this means to me better as the example in the paper is N=133=7*19 and I don't really get how 7 and 19 are the same length, but it isnot 100% relevant to the question).

Then, to get the wanted random bit, you'd need to take the [parity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parity.html) of 
[image] where [image].

The sequence of the series b will have a period "usually equal to [image] where the function λ is the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Therefore, you can try different numbers as N, calculate [image] and ensure that it is bigger than the amount of buts you want to be totally random.

Reading the wikipedia article about the Blum Blum Shub algorithms seems to suggest that you'd just want to have a very big N.